# Elegant way to filter a record with nullable field in SQL using nullable parameter

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with nullable field:

```
create table T1
(
    ID int not null primary key,
    KeyValue varchar(50) null
)
```

and also there is a parameter @KeyField varchar(50) that is nullable

I want to come up with a nice test comparing field and parameter so that
a) they both are equal or 
b) both nulls so I can write a simple WHERE statement to find the records.

This one below looks long to me and I am concerned about it's performance in SQL.

```
WHERE KeyValue = @KeyValue or KeyValue is null and @KeyValueIsNull
```

Comment: That *would* be the way to do it though.

Comment: Oh, I figured it! nullif(@value1, @value2) is null

Comment: That's have worse performance @ben92 .

Comment: yes, it does... sad

Comment: WHERE EXISTS (SELECT Col INTERSECT SELECT @Param)

Comment: Unfortunately, elegant compact code in SQL often performs worse than longer winded code.

Comment: @Martin Smith If you post that as an answer I'll vote it up.

Comment: I like a lot Martin's approach for multi-field criteria. Great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am concerned about it's performance in SQL.
>
> ```
> WHERE KeyValue = @KeyValue or KeyValue is null and @KeyValue IS NULL
> ```

There is no need to be. SQL recognises this pattern is just a straightforward equality operation with `IS` semantics rather than `EQ` semantics (so two nulls will compare as equal rather than unknown). If you have a covering index on `KeyValue` you can expect to see a straightforward index seek.

You can also get the same ([fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=99d29d379b360375b7c93cd37a65cd6b)) with

```
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT KeyValue INTERSECT SELECT @KeyValue)
```

though this isn't much shorter when just comparing a single column.

See Paul White's blog post [Undocumented Query Plans: Equality Comparisons](https://www.sql.kiwi/2011/06/undocumented-query-plans-equality-comparisons.html?m=1) for more on this topic.

Answer (score 1):

index scan

```
WHERE NULLIF(KeyValue, @KeyValue) is NULL
```

index seek

```
WHERE KeyValue = @KeyValue or KeyValue is null and @KeyValue Is Null
```

So, long and clear and fast wins over short and confusing and slow.

Comment: Yes.  And while that formulation is perfectly correct, it's unlikely all your future maintainers have a firm grasp on boolean operator precedence in TSQL. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/operator-precedence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no null-safe equal in Sql Server, unlike in MySQL for example, that implements `<=>`.

One way is to use `OR` like you do (this is a it longer to write but it’s my preferred solution since the logic is clear to see).

If you know in advance a value that is *not* present in the column (eg the empty string), you can use `coalesce()` on both sides of the operator:

```
coalesce(keyValue, '') = coalesce(@keyValue, '')
```

The downside of this approach is that it won’t be able to take advantage of an index so this should perform worse than `OR` (which itself is usually quite slow).

Comment: But this would cause the query to be non-SARGable; it'll have worse not better performance.

Comment: @Larnu I agree that this is less efficient than `OR`. Updated my answer to mention it.

Comment: The pattern with OR in this case is recognised as a simple equality using IS semantics. https://www.sql.kiwi/2011/06/undocumented-query-plans-equality-comparisons.html?m=1

Answer (score 0):

I will recommend firing 2 SQLs for achieving both simplicity and far better performance. This solution looks simple to be ignored but in my experience it is often the best choice to avoid SQL complexity.

In the java, t-sql (or whatever other language you use) fire 2 sql based on the condition.

When @KeyValue is not null fire  `WHERE KeyValue = @KeyValue`
When @KeyValue is null fire `WHERE KeyValue is null`.

If index is present on KeyValue then range scan will happen on it which is pretty efficient. As compared to OR condition where range scan will happen twice. As compared to NULLIF(..) where index full scan will happen.